# Disorganized or Unorganized?

Tags: word-usage, differences, negative-prefixes

Does anyone here know the difference between *unorganized* and *disorganized*?

As far as I know, *disorganized* refers to something that was once organized and now isn't, and *unorganized* refers to something that lacks organization from the start. 
Is that correct?

Comment: I use "unorganized" to imply fecklessness, like apathetic voters, and "disorganized" to imply uselessness, like the papers on my desk.

Comment: [Unorganized](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unorganized) and [disorganized](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disorganized).

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly attempt to construct two different usages along the lines you suggest but they would pass most native speakers by.

Consider the very strong case for regarding 'disinterested' and 'uninterested' as having very, and usefully distinct meanings. Some native speakers, myself included, insist on this distinction.

Even in that case the distinction is very frequently not observed, to the extent that modern dictionaries record them as being used as synonyms:

> Disinterested is sometimes used to mean not interested, but many people consider this use to be incorrect. Compare uninterested.[Cambridge Dictionary]
>
> If you are disinterested in something, you are not interested in it. Some users of English believe that it is not correct to use disinterested with this meaning.[Collins]

"Some users of English", or even "many people" believing it is incorrect does not stop the rest believing 'disinterested' means the same as 'uninterested'. So if you want to be understood by everyone, you need to be careful.

Likewise if you wanted to use those unorganised and disorganised in the senses you describe you would need to explain that usage before doing so. Otherwise the reader/listener might assume they were synonyms.

Comment: Fair enough. I never really paid attention to the difference until I encountered both words in an English class about prefixes.

Comment: I don't agree with the conflation of 'disinterested' and 'uninterested' in your answer - in my experience, they retain their distinct usages. However, I do agree that the difference between 'disorganized' and 'unorganized' is lost in the common parlance of native speakers - at  least in the US. I will consider an upvote if you revise and edit this answer.

Comment: @Oldbag I have edited and expanded my answer. Just because you and I both dislike a usage does not stop others from using it.

Comment: Sorry. I should have been clearer. The use of 'disinterested' as a synonym for 'uninterested' is not common, as the usual use is intended to mean 'uninvolved' or, neutral, concerning an issue: as in, **disinterested parties**. US

Comment: @Oldbag Very common in the UK. So much so that I do not use 'disinterested' in that sense to a non-specialist audience without defining it for them.

Comment: Interesting... Usually it's Americans screwing up the Mother Tongue. (How's that for a clean sentence that sounds dirty?)

Answer (score 0):

Something *disorganized* either had its organization removed or lacks organization; something *unorganized* never was organized or lacks organization.

First, a clue to some difference between the two comes through in each word's etymology. From the Oxford English Dictionary, *disorganized* has an etymology that suggests it can have a more active sense of something ordered being *disorganized*:

> Unorganized: un- prefix1 + organized adj. Compare disorganized adj.
>
> Disorganized:  disorganize v. + -ed suffix1.

*Disorganize* is a verb that means to disrupt the order of something (Merriam-Webster). Consequently, as an adjective that was formed from the verb, *disorganized* may suggest that something formerly with order has been thrown into disorder. The Oxford English Dictionary for *disorganized* includes verbs suggesting some kind of loss:

> **Deprived** or destitute of organization; **having lost**, or being without, organic connection or systematic arrangement; **thrown into confusion**, disordered.

However, note that *disorganized* need not be something made disordered. The unbolded terms *destitute of organization*, *being without organic connection*, and *disordered* suggest that something could lack organization from the start. In Merriam Webster's example sentence "[The meeting was very disorganized](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disorganized)," nothing suggests whether the meeting was always disorganized or whether it became disorganized. Contexts allow for either case.

Meanwhile, *unorganized* doesn't come from a verb and serves as a general description of a state. The verb *unorganize* (sic) [does not exist in the dictionaries I consulted](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unorganize) and it is relatively uncommon as a search result. Something *unorganized* lacks organization ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unorganized)).

So the two terms are somewhat differentiated, but that differentiation is subtle. My desk may be either disorganized or unorganized, but it might be odd to describe a routing army as unorganized unless they were unorganized from the start. *Disorganized* would describe that the army had been put into disarray.